# linux/bash: remove text between two chars

Tags: bash, replace, sed, awk, tr

I have a file `file1` and it contains:

```
<     16 ./lnx/apps/vlc/tsconf_1.0-11_all.deb
<     16 ./lnx/apps/vlc/vlc
<   2000 ./lnx/apps/vlc/vlc-nox_2.0.8-1_i386.deb
<     16 ./lnx/apps/vlc/vlc-plugin-notify_2.0.8-1_i386.deb
<     32 ./lnx/apps/vlc/vlc-plugin-pulse_2.0.8-1_i386.deb
<     16 ./lnx/cmds/64bit_ubuntu_add_i386
<     16 ./lnx/cmds/acroread_dl
<     16 ./lnx/cmds/dl_from_gdrv
<     16 ./lnx/cmds/dpkg_install_list_in_txt_file
<     16 ./lnx/cmds/find_and_replace
<     16 ./lnx/cmd/pearl_script.ps1
<     16 ./lnx/cmds/rm_using_find
<     16 ./lnx/cmds/wget_dl_whl_ws
```

I want to remove everything between `<` and `./` (or between `\n` and `./`) excluding `./`, so the output would be the following:

```
./lnx/apps/vlc/tsconf_1.0-11_all.deb
./lnx/apps/vlc/vlc
./lnx/apps/vlc/vlc-nox_2.0.8-1_i386.deb
./lnx/apps/vlc/vlc-plugin-notify_2.0.8-1_i386.deb
./lnx/apps/vlc/vlc-plugin-pulse_2.0.8-1_i386.deb
./lnx/cmds/64bit_ubuntu_add_i386
./lnx/cmds/acroread_dl
./lnx/cmds/dl_from_gdrv
./lnx/cmds/dpkg_install_list_in_txt_file
./lnx/cmds/find_and_replace
./lnx/cmd/pearl_script.ps1
./lnx/cmds/rm_using_find
./lnx/cmds/wget_dl_whl_ws
```

I tried these commands (their output was the exact input file):

```
$ sed -n '/</,/ ./ p' file1
$ sed 's/< .* " ."/./' file1
$ sed -e 's/<\n[^ .]>/<\n.>/g' file1
$ sed -e 's/\(<\).*\(.\)/\1\2/' file1
```

Probably it’s only a simple thing, but I am new at sed/awk/tr/grep/find commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ sed 's/[^.]*//' file
./lnx/apps/vlc/tsconf_1.0-11_all.deb
./lnx/apps/vlc/vlc
./lnx/apps/vlc/vlc-nox_2.0.8-1_i386.deb
./lnx/apps/vlc/vlc-plugin-notify_2.0.8-1_i386.deb
./lnx/apps/vlc/vlc-plugin-pulse_2.0.8-1_i386.deb
./lnx/cmds/64bit_ubuntu_add_i386
./lnx/cmds/acroread_dl
./lnx/cmds/dl_from_gdrv
./lnx/cmds/dpkg_install_list_in_txt_file
./lnx/cmds/find_and_replace
./lnx/cmd/pearl_script.ps1
./lnx/cmds/rm_using_find
./lnx/cmds/wget_dl_whl_ws
```

Comment: Thank you, Ed. This cmd is what I wanted. I see you are great programmer since you commented on 2 of 5 answers on my question and even was the very first to answer it :)

Answer (score 3):

How about (or am I missing something):

```
$ awk '$0=$NF' file
./lnx/apps/vlc/tsconf_1.0-11_all.deb
./lnx/apps/vlc/vlc
./lnx/apps/vlc/vlc-nox_2.0.8-1_i386.deb
./lnx/apps/vlc/vlc-plugin-notify_2.0.8-1_i386.deb
./lnx/apps/vlc/vlc-plugin-pulse_2.0.8-1_i386.deb
./lnx/cmds/64bit_ubuntu_add_i386
./lnx/cmds/acroread_dl
./lnx/cmds/dl_from_gdrv
./lnx/cmds/dpkg_install_list_in_txt_file
./lnx/cmds/find_and_replace
./lnx/cmd/pearl_script.ps1
./lnx/cmds/rm_using_find
./lnx/cmds/wget_dl_whl_ws
```

Comment: **Note:** This **will not** work if your files and/or directories have spaces in them.

Answer (score 2):

Using sed:

```
sed -i.bak 's~^<.*[[:space:]]\(\./\)~\1~' file
```

OR

```
sed -i.bak 's~^<[^.]*\(\./\)~\1~' file

./lnx/apps/vlc/tsconf_1.0-11_all.deb
./lnx/apps/vlc/vlc
./lnx/apps/vlc/vlc-nox_2.0.8-1_i386.deb
./lnx/apps/vlc/vlc-plugin-notify_2.0.8-1_i386.deb
./lnx/apps/vlc/vlc-plugin-pulse_2.0.8-1_i386.deb
./lnx/cmds/64bit_ubuntu_add_i386
./lnx/cmds/acroread_dl
./lnx/cmds/dl_from_gdrv
./lnx/cmds/dpkg_install_list_in_txt_file
./lnx/cmds/find_and_replace
./lnx/cmd/pearl_script.ps1
./lnx/cmds/rm_using_find
./lnx/cmds/wget_dl_whl_ws
```

Assuming there are no directories ending with `<space>.`.

Comment: it's probably fine but worth mentioning it'd fail if any directory name ended with a `.`. Changing `.*` to `[^.]*` should remove that constraint.

Comment: Thanks Ed, I made it little more precise.

Answer (score 2):

You can use BASH regex matching.

```
while read -r; do
    [[ $REPLY =~ .*(\.\/.*) ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
done < file
```

Answer (score 1):

## Bash

```
while read -r _ _ file_details; do
  echo "$file_details"
done < your_file > your_file.edited
```

## Awk

```
awk '{ $1=""; $2=""; print; }'
```

OK, if those first white spaces are really irksome:

```
awk -F. '{printf ".";print $2}'
```

Comment: The bash loop will interpret backslashes and so convert `\t` to a tab, for example, the first awk script will add leading spaces and compress all other contiguous white space, and the second awk script will replace every space in each path with a newline.

Comment: @EdMorton Fixed, thanks. I left the second awk unchanged because it was never my intention to make that one terribly robust, as you can tell by my comment.